# Inequality using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve this inequality from text book in the chapter fundamental theorem of calculus.

$$
\left|
\int\limits^{\sqrt{3}}_{0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{3+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x
\right|
<\frac{\pi^{2}\sqrt{3}}{36}.
$$

Some hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy-Schwarz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{3+x^2}$$
Note that $f(x)\geq 0$. Since $x \to \arctan(x)$ is increasing, then

$$f(x)\leq\frac{\arctan(\sqrt{3})}{3+x^2}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3+x^2}\right)$$

for any $x \in [0,\sqrt{3}]$. Integrating both sides from $0$ to $\sqrt{3}$:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f(x)dx\leq \frac{\pi}{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{dx}{3+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi^2\sqrt{3}}{36}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice answer. I have edited it a bit to improve formatting. $\tag*{}$Also, for the future, it might not be a good idea to answer low quality questions like this one (where the author shows no effort to solve the problem on their own). This one, for example, is likely to be closed unless the author improves it. Some users may even downvote you if you answer such questions too often. (Wow, that was fast. This downvote wasn't me...)

Comment: Great, yesterday I asked to my functional analysis teacher and we solve in class in the same way.
The hint was, first get rid off of complicate integral and solve the easy, i.e., $\frac{1}{3+x^2}$. I agree, next time when I am stuck I will think couple of days before publish here. https://i.imgur.com/S11imOB.png